# Can I build an anti-fatigue standing mat myself?

Tags: health-and-safety

I thought about buying a anti-fatigue mat for healthier prolonged standing but unfortunately the price tag is quite high and they are not available in my country, so I would have to pay for additional shipping costs. I’m wondering what material these mats are made of and whether I could simply buy the raw material for a cheaper price. They appear to be made from high density polyurethane foam. I don’t need surface structure to prevent slipping, by the way.

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/product/B00EJ9PVFM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EJ9PVFM)
- [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005UA2WO2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005UA2WO2)

[image: Foam]

Comment: Try "play mats" (for children) or stall mats (for livestock) for two different densities of inexpensive matting. Like anything, shopping around is generally required, since there is always somene willing to charge a higher price and hope for suckers. Play mats are typically $1/sq ft.

Comment: A blanket, rug or a piece of carpet will help. You just need something a little cushier than the floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify your location.  However, a child's play mat, a yoga mat, a good quality carpet underlay, a doormat, or a scrap of high density foam from a dumpster all can serve the need you describe.